# django - Adding a custom title to forms in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using a formset and I want each from generated to display a numbered title for each unique form. So if I generate 5 forms, I want to have a text label display before the form fields that says "Form 1", "Form 2", ... "Form 5".

How do I:

1. Create a space in a form for such a plain informational text label?
2. Set the title for each form (I'm assuming in the template)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can put a label in template using `forloop.counter` before each form, something as below

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
        <label> Form - {{forloop.counter}} </label>
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized [the docs](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/tags.html) give the solution. You can access `{{forloop.counter}}` in the `Layout` and create a label using the `HTML` universal layout element:

> Note that you can still use a helper (in this case we are using the
>   helper of the form used for building the formset). The main difference
>   here is that helper attributes are applied to the form structure,
>   while the layout is applied to the formset’s forms. Rendering formsets
>   injects some extra context in the layout rendering so that you can do
>   things like:
>
> HTML("{% if forloop.first %}Message displayed only in the first form
>   of a formset forms list{% endif %}", Fieldset("Item {{ forloop.counter
>   }}", 'field-1', [...])